# WooCommerce Checkout Page's Buttons are not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

first of all i'm sorry for my english.

I will use Woocommerce. But Checkout page's buttons are not working. You see my problem in these links.

Shop Page: http://gencvefit.com/shop
And Checkout Page (My problem in this page): http://gencvefit.com/checkout

Please help me.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Please post a code example.

Answer (score 0):

It uses this wp-admin/admin-ajax.php url for ajax enabling the Process Order button on the checkout page. use F12 on your browser to check the response from admin-ajax.php on your network tab.

Also Be careful if you have locked down your wp-admin folder with .htaccess you might need to make this mod:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83650/adding-admin-ajax-php-to-the-frontend-good-or-bad-idea

Also some good solutions here, such as check the settings-General URLs, and php.ini memory to 64mb.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-check-out-not-worknig/page/3?replies=81